# Uwsgi dont response for requests

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am  running an app and using uwsgi with and  using docker compse so when it was working fine

suddenly the behavior became weird.

when I restart the container it is up and running and the logs are OK but then it can't get any request that i made so there is no response after removing the container and its volumes many times it worked fine but it doesn't work consistently.

so this behavior is random

uWSGI version  2.0.20

my docker version is 24.0.5

docker compose version is v2.20.2

and OS version is Linux (ubuntu 20.04)

this is my uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]

module = retrieval.wsgi:app

uid = test

gid = test

master = true

socket = 0.0.0.0:5005

chmod-socket = 660

vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

need-app = true

enable-threads = true

stats = /tmp/stats.socket

memory-report = true

strict = true

processes = %k

mules = 1
```

I tried to run uwsgi without docker-compose and it worked consistently and i tried many VMs with different kernel versions on the cloud but the same behavior and no indication of any problem

I am using Nginx

and iam testing with uwsgi-tools